# Что если нам блокировать олимпиадные задачи на неделю?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Снова [очередной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1036917/213987) вопрос, в котором автор честно признался, что находится на олимпиаде и выкладывает задачу для решения.

При текущем подходе подобные вопросы вызывают волну минусов и закрываются. Но возможно мы лишаем себя хороших вопросов, над которыми интересно поломать голову?

Я подумал, что если подобные вопросы блокировать на неделю, для того, чтобы гарантировать, что в течение недели никто не будет отвечать на вопрос и тем самым гарантировать, что пользы от решения задачи топикстартер не получит.

Я себе это вижу так: если кто-то заметил подобный вопрос, то он может тревогнуть модератора, который поставит блокировку [сроком в неделю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) на вопрос и добавит [олимпиады](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b), сам вопрос после закрытия можно поплюсовать, чтобы он никуда не пропал, когда блокировка автоматически снимется, то можно будет давать ответы.

Как думаете, это хороший вариант или это можно будет как-то обойти хитрым образом?

Comment: "Но возможно мы лишаем себя хороших вопросов, над которыми интересно поломать голову?"

Почти любой сборник задач по программированию — это список вопросов над которыми можно "поломать голову" (только зачем?).

Answer (score 8):

Обстоятельства, которые привели автора к созданию вопроса, вообще не должны иметь значения при решении "закрывать или нет".  Просто потому, что это невозможно формализовать.

Вопрос выше - это отличный пример. Ситуация - автор на олимпиаде, решил все задачи, кроме этой. Попытался решить сам - не получилось. Притащил задачу на SO.

Вопрос закрыт с причиной

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос

Автор пытался решить задание самостоятельно? Очевидно, да. Условие соблюдается - да. Ок, вопрос допустим. Почему он до сих пор закрыт?

---

На самом деле вопрос стоило бы закрыть как "непонятна суть вопроса". Из текста ведь на  непонятно, в чем **техническая** суть вопроса. Может автор не может данные прочитать? Или может не может вывести. Кто его знает:

> Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, **в чём именно вы видите проблему**, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

... или просто оставить открытым.

Вводить какой-то дополнительный механизм именно для борьбы с олимпиадными задачами не стоит. Шанс, что на олимпиадный вопрос будет дан ответ до того, как олимпиада закончится - почти никакой. Сложный заминусованный вопрос - это, на самом деле, хорошо. Кто-то из участников мог бы реверс на таком заработать. Свои собственные знания подтянуть.

А если никто не захочет - бот снесет вопрос, даже если его не закроют. Привлекать пятерых закрывающих только ради того, чтобы бот снёс его чуть раньше - напрасная трата времени и сил.

Comment: Реверс же отменили, теперь надо чтобы после ответа вопрос ушёл в плюс (((

Comment: @Qwertiy пора расчехлять твинков.

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос минусуют и закрывают, значит сообщество не хочет видеть такие вопросы.

А подобное предложение идёт в обход этого, что, как по мне, не правильно.

Другое дело, если было бы обсуждение того, **хотим ли мы видеть на сайте олимпиадные задачи, от авторов, которые даже не удосуживаются сами их решить**?

Comment: Если вопрос минусуют -- это вполне может означать выражение негативного отражения к автору вопроса и к этически неприемлемой ситуации. Предложение как раз позволяет развести разные стороны вопроса: топикстартер не получит ожидаемой выгоды, а вопрос сам по себе может быть хорошим и на него можно будет дать ответ.

Comment: И как давно мы начали позиционировать  себя почти уже как ИТУ (ну, или как минимум педагогическое учреждение),  а не общество взаимопомощи?

Comment: @avp я всегда был против "домашек". Другое дело, если человек покажет хоть какие-либо свои попытки решения вопроса. Иначе это просто медвежья услуга, а не помощь.

Comment: Кстати, а кому именно "медвежья услуга"?  Спрашивающему, преподавателю, работодателю? И каким образом неумелые попытки как-то решить задачу меняют дело? / Мне кажется, что закрывая-убивая домашки мы на самом деле мешаем поднимать свой уровень тем, кто (пока) может только их решать (и зарабатывать тут репу на этом)

Comment: @avp спрашивающему, конечно. Толку ему от того, что он просто получит готовое решение? Единственный положительный момент в этом всём только для новых пользователей, которых заинтересует вопрос. Но для олимпиадных задач есть специализированные сайты.

Comment: Не соглашусь. Спрашивающему только очевидная польза. Он получит свой зачет (или даже место на олимпиаде) и будет гулять, довольный жизнью. Это уже хорошо. Программиста же нельзя выучить. Он или создан для этого или нет. От учителей тут может зависеть только скорость его роста (если он потенциально способен стать программистом)

Comment: Это плохая услуга мне (в прошлом) и другим честным олимпиадчикам, которые решают сами. Возможность смухлевать на олимпиаде дискредитирует саму идею олимпиад как честного соревнования. В качестве экстремального примера, представьте себе шахматиста, который выкладывает в процессе игры позицию на доске с просьбой к коллективному разуму помочь.