# Предложение ввести метку «сложные учебные задания»

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, создание-метки

Заметил, что ныне пошёл гон у "минусёров"*, и вот я подумал, может ввести метку «сложные учебные задачи», ибо знаю, что минусёры весьма умны и любят головоломки и олимпиадные задачи, ибо что-то простое они воспринимают как призыв к закрытию вопроса.

А то от их голосов за закрытие многие могут пострадать :-( И это печально.

- *минусёры - это участники ruSO, ориентированные на 
  отрицательные эмоции и результаты.*

Comment: @suvitruf-says-reinstate-monica прям весь смысл меняется от такого редактирования

Comment: Я убрал вульгарщину.

Comment: Я как-то думал над [подобным вопросом про олимпиадные задачи](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9660/213987), положительного отклика в сообществе не увидел. Непростой это вопрос как сбалансировать интересные вопросы и "домашку", последний год-два не вижу каких-то прорывных решений, пока всё примерно одни и те же варианты обсуждаются и, увы, с довольно большим числом побочек.

Comment: Не понимаю любви сообщества к бюрократизации. Сейчас эту метку введем. Потом будет куча споров "Какое задание сложное? Критерии сложного задания.". Потом до метки "учебные задания средней сложности" дойдем и еще больше споров начнется.

Comment: Как эта метка будет работать? Что-то вроде: поставил метку и теперь нельзя закрывать вопрос? Суть предложения неясна.

Comment: Любой участник с репутацией 300 и больше может создать любую метку. Без всякого предложения. Вопрос - что с этой меткой делать?

Comment: @Эникейщик сжигать её, т.к. подобные мета-метки на основном сайте не приветствуются :D

Answer (score 3):

Это бессмысленное нововведение:

- Учебные задания закрывают, несмотря на сложность задания.
- Эта метка вряд ли будет использоваться: халявщики предпочитают вообще не разбираться в правилах сообщества, а никто другой не просит за себя решать.
- Если вы имеете в виду что-то вроде code-golf, то для этого есть отдельная метка.
- Что такое "сложное задание"? Нужно определение, иначе возникнут споры.

Answer (score -1):

Не следует забывать, что для многих это он-лайн игра 'заработай баллы' :) отсюда и количество с "качеством" этих самым "минуСёров"